# How can I display the contents of demo_test.txt when I hover over a link? Where am I going wrong, and how should my code look?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Where am I going wrong, and how should my code look?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
 $(".button").hover(function(){ $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt", success:function(result){ $("#div1").html(result); }}); }); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

 <div id="div1"><a href="#" class="button">Hover me</a></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event listener is not getting initialized. Either wrap your hover listener in `$(document).ready` or place the javascript after the `.button` in the DOM:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").hover(function(){ $.ajax({url:"demo_test.txt", success:function(result){ $("#div1").html(result); }}); }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="div1"><a href="#" class="button">Hover me</a></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code.

Comment: Thankyou. How can I get the text to disappear after I have finished hovering?

Comment: I do not have a high enough reputation to upvote, but you do get my tick!

Answer (score -2):

Your ajax request should point to a controller action method in your backend code.  Do the processing there to read the file and return this as a String to manipulate as you like client side.

```
$.ajax({
        cache: true,
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        url: '/SomeAction/GetText',
        success: function (msg) {

           // do your replace here

        }

    });
});
```